# Windows keyboard shortcuts not working in Sysinternals Desktops

Tags: windows-7, sysinternals

**[Windows Sysinternals Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx)** is a virtual desktop utility that provides up to 4 *virtual desktops*. It creates a *Windows desktop object* for each additional virtual desktop other than the default one. I am finding that Windows **keyboard shortcuts** (like `Win+E` to launch Explorer) work only in Desktop 1 and not in the newly created Desktop 2, 3 and 4!

What is the cause of this problem? How can I get my keyboard shortcuts working with the other virtual desktops?

Comment: I have Desktops on Win7 and Win+E, Win+D, etc. work fine. I have problems with clipx and similar programs because of different desktop objects used by each virtual desktop.

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me too. According to [official documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881), Desktops create a new `explorer.exe` process for each new desktop created. Maybe this is the problem, and the new `explorer.exe` processes do not capture keyboard shortcuts events like the `Win+E` one.